# RoR - Table with 'View More' expand and collapse into new table row

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a table that has;
- row 1 with three columns
- row 2 one column

In the 3rd columns of row 1 - I am trying to add a 'View More'. Once this is clicked it will reveal Row 2 (hidden unless 'View More' is clicked).

Here is the code:

```
<div class="row host_tours_background">
    <div class="container">

        <table class="table table-condensed" style="border-collapse:collapse;">

            <% @tours.each do | tour |%>
                <tr>
                    <td class="col-md-3 host_tours_image">
                        <%= image_tag tour.tourimage.url (:medium)%></td>
                    <td class="col-md-6 host_tours_detail">
                        <h4 style="color:#55c7eb"><%= tour.title %></h4>
                        <h4><!--%= link_to tour.title,tour %--></h4>
                        <p><%= tour.text %></p>
                        <p><%= tour.id %></p></td>
                    <td class="col-md-3 host_tours_price">
                        <h5>RM</h5>
                        <h4><%= tour.price_for_adult %></h4>
                        <h5>/ adult</h5>
                        <h5>Child Price</h5>
                        <h4><%= tour.price_for_child %></h4>
                        <h5>Other Here</h5>
                        <% tour_id = "tour-id-#{tour.id}" %>

                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td colspan="12" class="hiddenRow">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="read-more-state" id="<%= tour_id %>" />
                        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target">Activity: <%= tour.tour_category_id %></span></p>
                        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target">Duration: <%= tour.duration %></span></p>
                        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target">Notes: <%= tour.notes %></span></p>
                        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target">Start Time: <%= tour.start_date %></span></p>
                        <p class="read-more-wrap"><span class="read-more-target">Location: <%= tour.location %></span></p>
                        <label for="<%= tour_id %>" class="read-more-trigger"></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>

            <% end %>

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

-- 
From the above code. - in column 3 of row 1 under "Other Here' I want to add the 'View More' button.

What is currently happening
- the data is being managed correctly
- the display is broken as the button sits below the first row about 100px down
- the space between row 1 and the button is blank (but when you click the button the data is shown)

How do I get the button in the correct place?
Have table row 2 hidden (remove the 100px spacing)
Activate 'View More' to reveal table row 2?

Thanks for the help??

Comment: hi man you didn't close 3rd `td` in `th` please check it

Comment: @uzaif I closed the 3rd one.. same problem still persists